# Is possible recover mysql data folder

Tags: mysql, data-recovery, aws

I used the below commands to delete a mysql my Ubuntu server 14 on aws amazon.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I would like to **retrieve** data from the /var/lib/mysql.

It's possible?